# ruby ftp time out problem

Tags: ruby, ftp

I have written a ruby script to retrieve data from an ftp site using ftp/net. Everything seem to work well except the last stage where its timing out when it attempts to download the file itself.  Any ideas why that is the case?  'samples' has one directory now for test purposes.

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk')
ftp.login
puts "connected!"

errors = []
samples = ["SRR016000"]

samples.each do |sample|
  files = ftp.chdir("vol1/fastq/SRR016/#{sample}/")
  puts "changed directory"
  #files = ftp.list('SRR*')
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(20) do
      ftp.getbinaryfile("#{sample}_1.fastq.gz")
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
     errors << "File download timed out for: #{sample}"
     puts errors.last
  end
end

ftp.close
puts "All done!"
```

Comment: The file is pretty big. Are you sure that 20 seconds is enough to download it?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer:  Needed to add the following

```
ftp.passive = true
```

Comment: Why don't you use your original account?

Comment: Don't change the original, if you do then the question won't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file you're trying to download? Are you sure that it's going to finish downloading in 20 seconds? Have you tried removing the `begin/rescue/end` block?

Comment: No but I've done it without the Timout and it went for long until it crashed and ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:241:in `readline': Connection timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

Comment: Perhaps my answer was vague.  So I have removed the begin/rescue/end block and it complained after around 15 minutes of ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:241:in `readline': Connection timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

Answer (score 0):

The code above worked fine for me after adding two `require` statements and changing Timeout value from 20 to 20_000.

Comment: Thanks for that, Im trying this now

Comment: Is there a way of trying to see the % download of the file as its downloading it?

Comment: Thanks for that, but Im still getting the `readline': Connection timed out error, even with 20000 seconds timeout.  Its getting so frustrating now?  Its not even printing the download progress you have done.  Any ideas whats going on? Thanks again

Comment: You have no connection to the FTP. Are you able to connect to the FTP site directly, without Ruby? And could you get the full stack trace?